# How can I create this kind of option?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, button

I need to know the name of a "button-function" in cocoa/ios.. By example, when you go in to the image library on your iPhone, and click an image to make it full screen, and then click the square with an arrow pointing out, allowing you to send the image with mail, text message etc.. What is that "funciton" called? I want to implement this to my app, but have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: xcode is just an IDE and irrelevant for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIDocumentInteractionController` is the controller that is fired.

[Previewing and Opening Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Now I just have to figure out how to display it in the action method of a normal button.